# How to set number format on multiple columns?

Tags: excel, vba

This should be a simple fix but I cannot find an answer to this online. I am trying to apply a number format for multiple columns.

```
.Columns("W:Y, AB:AC").NumberFormat = "#,##0.0%;[Red](#,##0.0%)"
```

However, when I apply this code, I get a "mismatch" error. I can run this code fine if split up the column ranges but when I try to combine them to make my code more efficient, it fails.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

GCC

Comment: Try using `Range` instead of `Columns`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per Peh's response below:

```
Range("W:Y,AB:AC").NumberFormat = "#,##0.0%;[Red](#,##0.0%)"
```

Comment: You can omit the selecting.

Comment: Please never use `.Select` [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) • `Range("W:Y,AB:AC").NumberFormat = "#,##0.0%;[Red](#,##0.0%)"`